# two usb on motherboard, one on front

Tags: usb, motherboard, case

I bought a motherboard with two separate usb pinhead things (as in you need 2 cables to get two usb ports). The case I have (Cosair Obsidian 250d) has one big usb thing twice as thick to get two usb ports. What adapter would I need to use to get this working?

To clear up confusion:

I have the male counterpart to this cable on my motherboard:
[image: http://img.misco.eu/productmedia/htmlimages/cten/SRH/SRH-1/173711-front3.jpg]

On my case the cable has these ends:
[image: http://img1.buyincoins.com/gallery/motherboard-20-pin-to-usb-2-port_01.jpg]

Is there an adapter to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You can't plug in a USB 3.0 header into a USB 2.0 Header port.  This questions shows a lack of research buy a converter cable.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different USB 3.0 to USB 2.0 converter cables out there you can buy.
This [Silverstone Tek Internal 19-Pin USB3.0 to USB2.0 Adapter Cable (G11303050-RT)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0098FSJ92) from Amazon should work for you. It's only $10 too!
[image]

**Note**: You will not be able to get USB 3.0 speeds out of the USB connector. You will only get USB 2.0 speeds. This is because the adapter only allow the pins for USB 2.0 to be accessed (USB 3.0 uses more pins to carry more data).